# QTreeView/QFileSystemModel - Comparing files & showing colour

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I have 2 QTreeViews both with a QFileSystemModel attached. One is a local directory and one is pointing at a server.

I am looking to change the colors of text on files based on its relation to the opposite location. For example:
If both server and local have the same modified time - set to green
If the server is more up to date - set local to red, server to orange. Etc etc.

I have had multiple working examples of this but I keep running into the same roadblock, sluggy UI response. I am using the data() function in both QFileSystemModels to achieve this, I tried threading the operation outside of data() to return the color back but it just makes all my files turn in to a light show. Files will randomly go green/red/orange based on me moving the mouse around.

I currently have the date modified column visible as a workaround but it doesn't help the user know if they have a file from the server locally already.

Has anyone got anything like this working without having the UI chug? Or even found a method to return the result from a thread and have it work for the correct entry?

I appreciate this may look a little messy but here is where I init the roots (some of these globals are used elsewhere)

```py
def initRoots(self, loc):
    '''
    This function sets the starting directories for both server and local
    Does not handle anything except top level
    '''
    global localMask
    global serverMask
    global serverRoot
    global userRoot
    global GserverModel
    global GlocalModel

    if loc == "Server":
        self.serverRoot = self.cb_serverWorkspace.currentText()
        serverRoot = self.serverRoot
        self.serverModel = ServerFileSystemModel()
        GserverModel = self.serverModel
        self.tv_serverFiles.setModel(self.serverModel)
        #self.serverModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        self.serverModel.setRootPath("")
        self.tv_serverFiles.setRootIndex(self.serverModel.index(self.serverRoot))
        self.tv_serverFiles.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.tv_serverFiles.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
        self.tv_serverFiles.hideColumn(1)
        self.tv_serverFiles.hideColumn(2)
        self.tv_serverFiles.setColumnWidth(0,400)

    if loc == "Local":
        self.userRoot = self.cb_localWorkspace.currentText()
        userRoot = self.userRoot
        self.localModel = LocalFileSystemModel()
        GlocalModel = self.localModel
        self.tv_localFiles.setModel(self.localModel)
        #self.localModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
        self.localModel.setRootPath("")
        self.tv_localFiles.setRootIndex(self.localModel.index(self.userRoot))
        self.tv_serverFiles.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        self.tv_localFiles.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
        self.tv_localFiles.hideColumn(1)
        self.tv_localFiles.hideColumn(2)
        self.tv_localFiles.setColumnWidth(0,400)
```

Then my two QFileSystemModels are pretty much this (This is my non-threaded example)

```py
class ServerFileSystemModel(QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServerFileSystemModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        
        try:
            global GlocalModel
            global GserverModel
               
                
            serverPath = self.filePath(index)

                
            localMask = userRoot + "/"
            serverMask = serverRoot + "/"
                
            newPath = serverPath.replace(serverMask, localMask)
 
            serverIndex = GserverModel.index(serverPath)
            localIndex = GlocalModel.index(newPath)
                
            if role == QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole and serverPath.endswith(".fbx") and os.path.exists(newPath) and downloading == False:
                  
                  
                if GlocalModel.lastModified(localIndex) == GserverModel.lastModified(serverIndex):
                    return QtGui.QColor("#58cd1c")
                      
                if GlocalModel.lastModified(localIndex) < GserverModel.lastModified(serverIndex):
                    return QtGui.QColor("#ed7011")
                  
                if GlocalModel.lastModified(localIndex) > GserverModel.lastModified(serverIndex):
                    return QtGui.QColor("#ed1111")
              
                       
      
            return super(ServerFileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
        except:
            return super(ServerFileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
```

Anything else just let me know.

*******EDIT*************

I was asked to put minimal replicable code so here we go

**MainWindow**

```
class WorkspacerUI(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WorkspacerUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.userRoot = "D:/OCooke_Workspace"
        self.serverRoot = "D:/OCooke_Server"
        
        self.initRoots("Local")
        self.initRoots("Server")

    
    def initRoots(self, loc):
        '''
        This function sets the starting directories for both server and local
        Does not handle anything except top level
        '''
                
        if loc == "Server":
            self.serverModel = ServerFileSystemModel()
            self.tv_serverFiles.setModel(self.serverModel)
            #self.serverModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
            self.serverModel.setRootPath("")
         self.tv_serverFiles.setRootIndex(self.serverModel.index(self.serverRoot))
            self.tv_serverFiles.setUniformRowHeights(True)
            self.tv_serverFiles.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
            self.tv_serverFiles.hideColumn(1)
            self.tv_serverFiles.hideColumn(2)
            self.tv_serverFiles.setColumnWidth(0,400)

        if loc == "Local":
            self.localModel = LocalFileSystemModel()
            self.tv_localFiles.setModel(self.localModel)
            #self.localModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.rootPath())
            self.localModel.setRootPath("")
            self.tv_localFiles.setRootIndex(self.localModel.index(self.userRoot))
            self.tv_serverFiles.setUniformRowHeights(True)
            self.tv_localFiles.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(True)
            self.tv_localFiles.hideColumn(1)
            self.tv_localFiles.hideColumn(2)
            self.tv_localFiles.setColumnWidth(0,400)
```

**QRunnable with Signals**

```
class WorkerSignals(QObject):

    finished = Signal()
    result = Signal(object)
    progress = Signal(int)


            
            
class ColourWorker(QRunnable):
    '''
    Worker thread

    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.

    :param callback: The function callback to run on this worker thread. Supplied args and
                     kwargs will be passed through to the runner.
    :type callback: function
    :param args: Arguments to pass to the callback function
    :param kwargs: Keywords to pass to the callback function

    '''

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ColourWorker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress
        self.kwargs['indexy']
        
        
        
    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done
```

**Finally the 2 QSystemFileModels**

```
class ServerFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ServerFileSystemModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.colour = None

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role == Qt.TextColorRole:
            worker = ColourWorker(self.execute_this_fn, indexy = index) # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
            worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)
            worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
            # Execute
            self.threadpool.start(worker)


            return self.colour
        return super(ServerFileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
        
#  

 
    def execute_this_fn(self, progress_callback, indexy):

        serverPath = self.filePath(indexy)
              
        localMask = "D:/OCooke_Workspace/"
        serverMask = "D:/OCooke_Server/"
              
        #create an expected path to the local using the server address
        # D:/OCooke_Server/2020/file1 turns into  D:/OCooke_Workspace/2020/file1
        newPath = serverPath.replace(serverMask, localMask)

        #Check the stat time between the two locations
        if os.stat(newPath).st_mtime == os.stat(serverPath).st_mtime:
            return QColor("#58cd1c")
        if os.stat(newPath).st_mtime < os.stat(serverPath).st_mtime:
            return QColor("#ed7011")
        if os.stat(newPath).st_mtime > os.stat(serverPath).st_mtime:
            return QColor("#ed1111")

        else:
            return None
        
 
    def print_output(self, s):
        #return the value of color
        self.colour = s
        
 
    def thread_complete(self):
        #ive tried passing the color once the thread completes, no joy
        pass



    
    
class LocalFileSystemModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocalFileSystemModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):


        return super(LocalFileSystemModel, self).data(index, role)
```

**MAIN**

```
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = WorkspacerUI()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please provide a [MRE] and improve the indentation

Comment: Your example is far from being *minimal* nor *reproducible*, but that is not the main issue: the `data()` function of a model should return *instantly*, meaning that no blocking (nor thread-related) function should go there, and that's because an item view might call `data()` hundreds or thousands times for each second, even when just hovering the mouse over items and even for the *same* items. Frankly, I believe your system is far too complex for your needs, and I'd suggest you to rethink the whole concept based on the fact that you're using fixed paths with (possibly) the same structure.